# Как сделать кнопку одинаковой по размеру в разных браузерах?

Tags: css, кроссбраузерность

В Chrome кнопка отображается нормально, а в Firefox такая беда:

[image]

Comment: что то мне подсказывает что в стиль к этой кнопке нужно добавить: `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-sdelat-knopku-vnutri-polya-dlya-poiska